# group by and select other columns that are not in aggreate functions works?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that in a query with group by clause, you can only select the columns in group by clause or using aggregate functions. But in my case below it works (project_name column). I want to know the logic. And under which conditions this works?

project Table

| id | name | xxxxx. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p001 | ML1 | -------- |
| p002 | AI2 | -------- |

uer_liked_projects Table

| project_id | user_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p001 | u001 | -------- |
| p001 | u002 | -------- |
| p002 | u001 | -------- |
| p002 | u003 | -------- |

My Query:

```
SELECT proj.id, proj.name, COUNT(*) as count_user
FROM project proj
JOIN uer_liked_projects ulp
ON proj.id = ulp.project_id
GROUP BY proj.id
```

Result:

| id | name. | count_user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p001 | ML1 | 3 |
| p002 | AI2 | 2 |

I suppose that the groupby is applied to primary_key, and in this case, you could select any other columns?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres implements this behavior which is defined in the ANSI-92 SQL standard.  When aggregating by a column which is unique, any other column can also be selected, because those columns are said to be *functionally dependent* on the unique column(s) which appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Put another way, if we know the `id` value for a record in the `project` table, we therefore also know the value for any other column from that table.  Hence, in your query, it is legitimate to aggregate only by the project `id`, but also select the name.

However, on some other databases, such as Oracle and SQL Server, this behavior is not supported.  There, you would have to use the following version of your query:

```sql
SELECT proj.id, proj.name, COUNT(*) AS count_user
FROM project proj
INNER JOIN uer_liked_projects ulp
    ON proj.id = ulp.project_id
GROUP BY proj.id, proj.name;
```

Here, we needed to add the `name` column to the `GROUP BY` clause to get the code to compile.

Comment: It isn't enough to be unique, it has to be the primary key.

Comment: @jjanes Maybe for Postgres, not for other databases (e.g. MySQL).  If you can provide a Postgres reference, I'm happy to edit my answer.